# how to store information in dump through php

Tags: php, html, gd

I want to store images created by php in real time. Currently each image is destroyed after creation, but instead I want to store the images in an unique folder on my website.

I have seen many websites that use a dedicated dump folder, e.g. `http://www.example.com/dump/4592898349.jpg`, and I was wondering if someone could explain to me how I could do that.

This is my html code with the form that starts the image generation:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="result.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my php code, which creates the image with the given text:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
    $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
    $text = $_GET['name'] ;
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image); 
?>
```

However, I still don't know where would be the best place to save the image.

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/imagejpeg, pay particular attention to its second (optional) parameter...

Comment: please don't give the links because I don't understand with that I understand with real Working examples

Comment: then you're not going to be get very far in this business. either learn to read documention, or find a different profession.

Comment: This example is for clearing up the memory i want to store them in an different location on website for eg( www.example.com/dump/.jpg)

Comment: @learner that is what Marc B is trying to tell you. if you look at the `imagejpeg()` function definition, then you can pass a filename as second parameter. Just pay attention, since image will be saved, but not echoed to the browser anymore, you will have to do a `readfile($img_filename)` to output the newly created image

Comment: @moderator i would appreciate this question being reopened again. the question was edited and the answers are worth reading for other users with similar questions. answers *unique filenames*, *displaying images* and *saving image data* unto *output buffering*. all close together bound to one topic. i believe this is worthwhile reading for beginners and forgettables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
```

to

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image,"imagefolderpath/image.jpg");
```

that will write the image to file, and not output the image...so...

```
$image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
readfile($image_url);
```

Comment: what if i want to set the image name which we get from the html input tag

Comment: i want to give image name to get it from the string `$_GET['name']`

Comment: yeah, and you have this line `$text = $_GET['name'] ;` where you assign it to $text....so it's the same thing.  I urlencoded it because I assume you want to use it again with a url, right?

Comment: you could have characters in the text, that someone would want to write on an image, that could also interfere with writing the file and being able to access it by url later...try naming files with + , ! or other characters

Comment: @RightClick i was so slow in typing, that my solution is similar to yours (but not copied), but i did add a version allowing same result with single disk access using `ob_start()`

Comment: @hexereisoftware yes, I like your second solution.  Looks like part of the goal is to keep some of the text in the filename.  Maybe a combination of our answers would be best, appending a unique id to the filename to keep something meaningful in the filename while preventing an overwrite?

Comment: @RightClick changed my sample to include your `rawurlencode(trim(..` solution, should be the best of both worlds now :)

Comment: nicely done.  that's why I'm always robin and you're batman

Comment: i want to call that image on the page including html  ` <html> <body <center><img src="dump/<?php $jpg_image?>.jpg</center> </body> </html> `i m using this code to get the current url of image from dump and show it on php is it correct

Comment: nope.  I don't think it's correct. for starters your markup would need to be `<img src="<?php echo $img_url;?>" />` and you need to make sure you use the same directory/filename/uniqueAppend....  so it depends which solution you used.  I don't know what you're using this for but I have a similar image project and when I create the files, I write the filename to a database so I can later query it to show them on a page.

Comment: I want to add some html to the page but i cannot do in the same page so i created a redirect too the page but the code `(img src="<?php echo $img_url;?>"/>` is not working any other method to add html to the php page

Comment: @learner, if you put it in another page, you need to get the filename into that variable somehow. You can't just copy some code into a new file and have it work, you need to pass that value to the page, pick it up like you did in the example `$_GET` and then you'll have a value for the filename so you can echo it back out in an img tag.  If this question is answered and you've moved on to a new topic, you might want to simplify this down to just what you're stuck with now, and start a new question.  I think we've moved beyond helping you learn, we can't just do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

So, not to be to strict on learners, the solution Marc B suggested was looking closer at the `imagejpeg()` function:

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

So there is a second optional parameter `$filename` which, when given, will tell GD to store the image in that file.

**BUT** it also says, that if you pass a filename, that the image is not automatically output to the browser, as it happens if you don't pass second parameter.

So there are three steps that you will have to accomplish:

1. Create unique filename
2. Save image to file
3. Display image in browser

Now the simplest solution would be:

```
/* --- create unique filename --- */

// get name passed or set default, this will be prepended to
// the unique filename to make it more readable
$prepend_filename = (isset($_GET['name']) ? rawurlencode(trim($_GET['name'])) : 'ing';

// set to the path where you want your images stored
$dirname = "/your/base/path/wherever/";
// use a while loop to make sure or new filename does not exist
while (true) {
    // now build unique filename
    $filename = uniqid($prepend_filename, true) . '.jpg';
    // if filename is unique (file does not exist) then exit loop 
    if (!file_exists($dirname . $filename)) break;
}

/* --- save image to file --- */

imagejpeg( $jpg_image, $dirname . $filename );

/* --- output image to browser --- */

readfile($dirname . $filename);
```

So this would basically work. The only thing that is not so nice about this solution is, that first you are accessing disk to write the image and then you have to re-access the file to output it to the browser. There is another technique that you could use to reduce file access:

```
/* --- output image to browser ---*/

// use output buffering to capture outputted image stream
ob_start();
// output the image to output buffer
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
// stop capture, flush output to browser and save as string
$img_data = ob_get_flush(); 

/* --- save image to file --- */

$fp = fopen($dirname . $filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $img_data);
fclose($fp);
```

So the advantage of this is, that you will not have to access disk twice.

If you don't want to return the image as raw image format, but actually want to display it right away in your html page, there are two methods.

**Method 1** (Removed comments on the repeated parts from above) Here we create the image, save it file and generate html output with the filename we created.

```
<?php

/* --- create unique filename --- */

$prepend_filename = (isset($_GET['name']) ? rawurlencode(trim($_GET['name'])) : 'ing';
$dirname = "/your/base/path/wherever/";
while (true) {
    $filename = uniqid($prepend_filename, true) . '.jpg';
    if (!file_exists($dirname . $filename)) break;
}

/* --- save image to file --- */

imagejpeg( $jpg_image, $dirname . $filename );

// now the difference starts

?><html>
    <head>
        <title>Your title here</title>
        <!-- the rest of your head here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://yourserver.com/your/base/path/wherever/<?php
            echo $filename; 
        ?>" width="100%" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Method 2** The start is the same as above, difference starts when saving image, we use the output buffering method again, but this time we pass the output to img tag as base64 encoded string. Nasty, nasty :)

```
/* Generating the filename is the same as above (not copied here).
   Output buffering same as prior sample, with one difference:
   Now we use ob_get_clean() instead of ob_get_flush() because
   we do not want to output image.
*/
ob_start();
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
$img_data = ob_get_clean();  // NOTE: ob_get_clean() not ob_get_flush()

/* --- save image to file --- */

$fp = fopen($dirname . $filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $img_data);
fclose($fp);

?><html>
    <head>
        <title>Your title here</title>
        <!-- the rest of your head here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php
            echo  base64_encode( $img_data );
        ?>" width="100%" />
    </body>
</html>
```

So here we used the buffered `$img_data` for writing the file to disk and for directly outputting it in the html page without browser having to call file from server (but with larger html source obviously)

Comment: I added the solution suggested by RightClick to add the rawurlencoded name parameter passed to the script, to give the filename a less random character

Comment: i want to call that image on the page including html `<html>
<body
<center><img src="dump/<?php $jpg_image?>.jpg</center>
</body>
</html>` i m using this code to get the current url of image from dump and show it on php is it correct

Comment: @learner so there you go, added two samples of how you could directly generate html source with your freshly generated image included.